# 907 invalid jar...data section too large for bb 8300

Tags: blackberry

if i remove obfuscation then jad file downloaded correcty and works fine.but if i add obfuscation then it is not downloading.i searched a lot,but not able to resolve the prob.please any body help me...

Comment: There really isn't enough info here to help meaningfully. 1) Is this jar or a cod you are installing

Comment: thnkx for giving reply..i am installing jad through ota

Answer (score 1):

Try a lower level of obfuscation or turn it off entirely, BlackBerry sometimes struggles with obfuscated midlets. If you have the time/resources it'd be much better to port the midlet to a native BlackBerry .cod

Comment: hi jonathan..i hav done it with bb 9500.it is working fine for that.the problem is for bb 8100 and 8310

Comment: hi...i have tried with lower level of obfuscation it is also not working...is there any other solution